# microsoft-graph message ID

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I call my mailbox using REST calls to MSGraph: 
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages
As expected I receive a Json with my mails.
To play with a specific mail (move, delete,forward, ...) I saw that the API should be called like
POST me/messages/**{id}**/forward
I can't target the message if I provide the value of the  ***id*** field that I get from the JSon. Where to find the correct **{id}** that I should use?
my result is like the example at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer see ***id:*** field when calling GET my mails. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id from JSON is OK. what you missing is you have not set the post conent for move/forward.

If you use the forward API, you should set the post content like below:

```
{
  "Comment": "FYI",
  "ToRecipients": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "XXX@XXX.onmicrosoft.com"
      }
    } 
  ]
}
```

This is the worked forward url for me(you can implement the move/delete like this too):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkAGNjZTcyZDJmLTkzMjYtNGQwNi05Y2UxLTc5NDk0NjEwNjJjMABGAAAAAAAUYpVLVYiKTINMO3MZR0H5BwB3NF3PTyl5QIQd59edwRO9AAAAAAEMAAB3NF3PTyl5QIQd59edwRO9AAApBI9fAAA=/forward
```

For information please see: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#ForwardDirectly